# JS Application REACTDOM.render() crash

Tags: node.js, react-redux, react-router, server-side-rendering, provider

I have a Javascript fullstack app that relies on React-Redux. However on compiling, I get an error message that reads, "Error: Input(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."
The code snippet follows;

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider >,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I have tried introducing a return loop in the code but I end up getting other errors.
On the surface, the code looks good but I can't say why my app still crashes

Comment: The error tells you this is related to an `Input` component that's not returning anything. The `ReactDOM.render()` snippet isn't related.

Comment: I am confused by the message, "...Nothing was returned from the render". Also everything points to my index.js file which contains the mentioned snippet.

Comment: The error message is pointing towards a component named `Input` which returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks. Will continue the debugging process